# nary search on a sorted array using openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

Extending the binary search logic for an n-ary search on a sorted vector , I tried the code below.Comparing with n-1 values and selecting the appropriate left and right.I have done linear search when size of vector is less than n. How do I use parallelization ?

```
int nary_search(vector<int> a,int key,int ary){
int l=0,r=a.size()-1;
while((r-l)>ary-1){
    //cout<<"left is "<<l<<" right is "<<r<<endl;
    int step=(r-l+1)/ary;
    int var=l+step;
    for(;var<=r;var+=step){
        if(key<=a[var])
        {
            r=var;
            l=var-step;
            break;
        }
        else{
            l=var;
        }
    }

}
//cout<<"left is "<<l<<"right is "<<r<<endl;
for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
    if(a[i]==key)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}
```

Also the break statement does not work for openmp so I tried to change it to this.

```
if(l<=key && key<=a[var])
        {
            r=var;
            l=var-step;

        }
        else{
            l=var+1;
        }
```

Comment: Did you use OpenMP for some simple loops before?

Comment: Yes #pragma omp parallel for but i cannot use this directly here I get incorrect results.

Comment: In that case you must show what you tried and how do your results look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nary_search(vector<int> a,int key,int ary){
int l=0,r=a.size()-1;
while((r-l+1)>ary){
    int step=(r-l+1)/ary;
    vector<int>key_values(ary-1,1);
    int var;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(var) shared(l)
    for(int cnt=0;cnt<ary-1;cnt++){

        var=l+step*(cnt+1);
        //cout<<var<<" "<<cnt<<" ";
        if(key<=a[var])
        {
            key_values[cnt]=0;
        }   

    }
    int sum=0;
    #pragma parallel for reduction (+:sum)
    for(int j=0;j<key_values.size();j++)
    {
        sum+=key_values[j];         
    }
    if(sum!=ary-1){
        r=l+step*(sum+1);
        l=r-step;
    }
    else {
        l=l+(step*sum);
    }


    //cout<<"left is "<<l<<" right is "<<r<<endl;
}
for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
    //cout<<"in ehre";
    if(a[i]==key)
        return i;
}
return -1;

}
```

here is my solution , what i have done is taken a key_values vector initialized to 1 of size number of keys(ary-1).If the key K<sub>i</sub> is grater than element to be searched , the corresponding 1 at the index i is made 0. Hence summing this key_values vector gives me the part in which the value to be searched  is located.